# Python Linspace passing in function return only one number

Tags: python, numpy

There is two case, the first one, my function Y1 return always the same number. In that case, it doesn't work, y is equal to a integer of 10 and not a array of one thousand 10. The second case, where it's return differents numbers, it works!

First case (Doesn't work as expected)

```
def Y1(x, N):
    return 10

x= np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
y= Y1(x,0) #In that case, it should create a array with 1000 numbers, but it only return one int, 10.

y value: 10 #when it should be [10 10 10 10 10 10...]
```

---

The othercases (Does work as expected)

```
def Y1(x, N):
    return x**2

x= np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
y= Y1(x,0) #it returns a array, all numbers are differents

y value: 
[4.00000000e+00 3.98400002e+00 3.96803210e+00 3.95209624e+00
 3.93619245e+00 3.92032072e+00 3.90448106e+00 3.88867346e+00
 3.87289792e+00 3.85715445e+00 3.84144304e+00 3.82576370e+00
 3.81011642e+00 3.79450121e+00 3.77891806e+00 3.76336697e+00
...]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Um, why do you expect an array to be returned from `Y1` when you are only returning an integer?

Comment: I added the values generated for both case.

Comment: You seriously believe that passing a numpy array as a parameter, that you don't even access from within the function, is somehow going to affect the function's result?

Comment: Sorry, I thought he was calling the function for each element of the array and not that he was passing the array in the parameter. I didn't know that you can make a exposant to an array without a loop. First time using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are returning the constant `10`.

In the second case, you are applying the operator `**2` to a np array, which overloads `**` and applies the power operation element-wise to the full array. This behaviour is known as broadcasting or vectorized aritmethic operations.

This broadcasting overload of the aritmethic methods allows behaviours as the following:

```
np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) + 1
>>> array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Which is what your second case uses and your first one does not.

You can learn more about this topic, for example, [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html).

If you want an array of shape 1000 full of 10s use [numpy.full](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) instead:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.full(1000, 10)
```